# One login page for multiple clients

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I had a laravel system built and trying to figure out how multiple clients can login using a single URL such as www.example.com/login

As the moment each user must have a unique url like below:

```
www.example.com/biz1/admin/login
www.example.com/biz2/admin/login
```

From what i can tell the code is getting the biz name from the url and adding it into the form, please see form below:

```
 <form action="{{ route('business.admin.authenticate', ['bzname' => $bzname]) }}" method="post" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="color: #fff" class="label">Email</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input style="color: #fff" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="color: #fff" class="label">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input style="color: #fff" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*********" name="password">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

This form then pasts to the function in the controller which is below:

```
  public function authenticate(Request $request, $bzname)
{
    $business = Business::where('business_name', $bzname)->first();
    $business_admin = BusinessAdmin::where('business_id', $business->id)->first();
    if(isset($business_admin))
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($business_admin->user_id);

        if($user->email === $request->input('email'))
        {
            if (Auth::guard('business')->attempt(['email'=>$request->input('email'), 'password'=>$request->input('password')]))
            {
                $permissions = [];
                session(['permissions' => $permissions]);
                return redirect()->route('business.admin.dashboard', ['bzname' => $bzname]);

            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->route('business.admin.login', ['bzname' => $bzname])->with('errorLogin', 'Ooops! Invalid Email or Password')->withInput();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('business.admin.login', ['bzname' => $bzname])->with('errorLogin', 'Ooops! Pls Enter Correct Business')->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking somehow in the $business parameter i need to get the bzname from the email linked to the client instead of getting it from the URL.

My knowledge is very basic at the moment and any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well cookies have a [path attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives) which you could leverage for the session to be separated per path

Comment: If all you want is the same login URL, there really shouldnt change much in the code. Instead of getting the biz name from the URL, you have to let the user choose it from a dropdown or something and send it with the form, because if you cannot get it from the URL (since you want the same login URL everywhere), you have to obtain it another way.

Comment: Issue is then other clients will know eachother, needs to be enter and email and password and somehow login without seeing the business name